# Resolving Reddit's "You've submitted too many links recently. Please try again in an hour." message

Tags: reddit

What are the necessary actions one needs to take to resolve this when the time when the message was first shown was more than an hour ago.

Is it due to

- too many links from the same domain or
- not commenting on posts or
- a bit of both?

Comment: Are you getting upboats? May be a spam limiting measure

Comment: No upboats, lost in the /new pile never to be seen again